# determine if a variable is an array of objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript

What is the best standard cross-browser method to determine if a variable is an array of objects.

Searching the web I couldn't find anything helpful, all I find is how to determine if a variable is an array, or if an array contains a specific object.

## Edit:

For example if I have this :

```
var arr = []; ==> false
var arr = [{},{}]; ==> true
var arr = [{},'']; ==> true
var arr = [new Date(),'']; ==> false
```

Comment: please add some use cases.

Comment: `console.log()`

Comment: You can try `Array.isArray(myArray) && myArray.every(x=> typeof x === 'object')`

Comment: Array of what kind of objects are you looking for exactly? Plain JS objects? Or can it be anything like date, promise, etc?

Comment: @NinaScholz please check my update

Comment: @boghyon please check my update

Comment: Why would `[{}, '']` return `true` if the last item is not an object? Also "object" is a very broad term in JS. If you want to exclude date objects, `typeof x === 'object'` doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

You could check if the variable is an array and if the first element of the array has the prototype of `Object`.

```js
function check(o) {
    return Array.isArray(o) && o[0] && Object.getPrototypeOf(o[0]) === Object.prototype || false;
}

var array = [[], [new Date(),''], [{},{}], [{},'']];

console.log(array.map(check));
```

Answer (score 0):

To check if an variable is an array you can use the **[Array.isArray()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray)** method like this:

```js
var anArray = [];
var notAnArray = {};

console.log(Array.isArray(anArray)); // logs "true"
console.log(Array.isArray(notAnArray)); // logs "false"
```

To check if an array is containing a specific object you can use **[Array.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)**:

```js
var myObjectArray = [{ a: 1 }];
var notMyObjectArray = [{ b: 1 }];

var checkIfSpecificObj = function(obj) {
  return obj.hasOwnProperty('a');
}

console.log(myObjectArray.some(checkIfSpecificObj)); // logs "true"
console.log(notMyObjectArray.some(checkIfSpecificObj)); // logs "false"
```

An to check if an array contains only objects you can use **[Array.every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)**

```js
var myObjectArray = [{}, {}, {}];
var notMyObjectArray = [{}, 'object', {}];

var checkIfOnlyObj = function(obj) {
  return typeof obj === 'object';
}

console.log(myObjectArray.every(checkIfOnlyObj)); // logs "true"
console.log(notMyObjectArray.every(checkIfOnlyObj)); // logs "false"
```